# How to properly load millions of files into an RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a very large set of json files (>1 million files) that I would like to work on with Spark.

But, I've never tried loading this much data into an RDD before, so I actually don't know if it can be done, or rather if it even should be done.

What is the correct pattern for dealing with this amount of data within RDD(s) in Spark?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to create directory, copy all the files to the directory and pass directory as path while reading the data.

If you try to use patterns in the directory path, Spark might run into out of memory issues.

Comment: Can you explain why it might run into memory issues when we use patterns in the path?

Comment: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Strategies-for-reading-large-numbers-of-files-td15644.html. It explains few of the issues especially on s3. Spark Context textFile function can be slow while traversing the directories matching the pattern. It serializes and also stores the metadata in memory of single thread.